# What default extension of KCachegrind

Tags: kcachegrind

I installed [KCachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kcachegrind/) on Ubuntu 14.10

When i click open button, i see Open dialog with default filter of file "Callgrind Profile Data" and not see my file. I must select "All files" in filter and then i see my file.

What extension must have a file that I saw him once when opening this dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked up the relevant source code [here](https://github.com/dtjm/kcachegrind/blob/4ac906f53cd06b2afba8b6d910f5ed860856afb5/qcachegrind/qcgtoplevel.cpp#L789-L797):

```
void QCGTopLevel::loadTrace()
{
    QString file;
    file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                    tr("Open Callgrind Data"),
                    _lastFile,
                    tr("Callgrind Files (callgrind.*)"));
    loadTrace(file);
}
```

It seems you need to prefix the filename with `callgrind.` to see the file by default. Or you can just select "All Files" from the dropdown.

Answer (score 5):

`callgrind.` did not work for me, so I [checked the code](https://github.com/dtjm/kcachegrind/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Callgrind%20Files) as well:

```
KUrl url = KFileDialog::getOpenUrl(KUrl(),
i18n("cachegrind.out* callgrind.out*|Callgrind Profile Data\n*|All Files"),
```

It seems `callgrind.out` works.